# Ubuntu will not install on my Windows 7

Tags: windows

I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop w/windows 7 64 bit / 3gb's Pentium (R) Dual-Core CPU. I downloaded newest edition of Ubuntu installed it as a dual boot beside windows 7. I selected the auto on screen too partisan my drive followed all instructions as required.

I than rebooted the system and got to select Ubuntu or windows 7. I selected Ubuntu as my os as it was loading I got this black screen with too much information to list here. It all looks like some error codes and something BIOS and so it's something I really don't understand. What I did next is reboot and got the something again. So I decided to download the OS all over again, try from scratch. The same-thing happen all over and the screen freezes up listing all the error codes and bios....not sure what to do next!!